# Android: Stop locationManager from updating within broadcastreceiver registered in manifest

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, locationmanager

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest file so that even after the app is wiped closed, it receives location updates.

```
<receiver android:name="com.tenforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.LocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="myBroadcast" />
        <action android:name="stopUpdating" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When the app is opened, it starts a `locationManager` using `pendingIntents`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("myBroadcast");
intent.putExtra("session_id", session_id);
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
lpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 58534, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//Register for broadcast intents
locationManager  = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, lpendingIntent);
```

This works great and even after app is closed i keep getting updates.  Now when I want to stop getting updates, I can set my `BroadcastReceiver` using `getComponentEnabledSetting()` and set it's state to disabled just fine.  But I'm pretty sure my `pendingIntent` would keep going through every minute.  I can't seem to figure out how to stop it.  I've tried recreating it inside the broadcastReceiver like many answers on here like so...

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 58534, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

But it just keeps on going through to the `BroadcastReceiver` after doing this every minute. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: how do you interact when app is closed? Do you use service(s)? I didnt understood much from this code but if all you want is to switch location updates then create a service so it will be working in background. Then you can use widgets to stop and start this service. Finally register your receivers inside service. and unregister when stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-create the PendingIntent exactly as it was when it was initially set up, and call [`removeUpdates()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates(android.app.PendingIntent)) in order to stop the location update callbacks.

Note that there is no need to call `cancel()` on the PendingIntent.

Also note that you would need to persist the `session_id` somehow, using a field in an Application subclass, or using SharedPreferences.  This is needed in order to re-create the PendingIntent correctly.

So, your code to stop location updates would be something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("myBroadcast");
intent.putExtra("session_id", session_id);
PendingIntent lpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 58534, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//Unregister for broadcast intents
LocationManager locationManager  = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.removeUpdates(lpendingIntent);
```

Comment: You are the man.  I didn't realize it had to be so exact.  Thought just same ID.  It works now, thanks so much.